# Added Cold Damage Support question

Tags: path-of-exile

I have a question about "Added Cold Damage Support". As you can see from the screenshot below:
[image]

It says that supported skills have 6 to 9 added cold damage. This support gem is linked to Caustic Arrow gem:
[image]

I am having troubles to understand my resulting damage for Caustic Arrow:
[image]

Why is main hand cold damage 10-15?
What exactly was enhanced by this support gem?

This is what equipped on me:
[image]

This is my skill tree:
[image]

Comment: Do you have other pieces of equipment that have added the 1-6 cold damage? That's really the only thing that I can think of as to why this would be 10-15.

Comment: you mean 4-6 cold damage?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the screen of what is equipped on me.

Comment: You also have presumably spent points onto your passive tree.  Without seeing that I couldn't tell you precisely why it's 10-15 damage, but I'd guess you have around 66% increased damage on your tree.

Comment: i edited the question to add my skill tree.

Comment: it looks like i have 71% increased projectile damage but I don't see how this can increase the cold damage, as cold is not a projectile, or am I missing smth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of your current skill tree. You gain 71% projectile damage from it.

Since your support gem is linked to a **projectile skill** it benefits from the bonus damage from your skill tree.

```
6*1.71 = 10.26, 9*1.71 = 15.39
```

It will also be affected by area damage or bow damage modifiers since it has that in the main skill gem description (the latter because you are using a bow).

You can see the skill descriptions and modifiers of every gem right below the name of the skill:

[image]

When it comes to determining whether it's a projectile or not you just have to watch the skill. Skills that look like projectiles but aren't are usually described in their attribute as "Melee" ([Lacerate](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Lacerate) for example).

The cold portion of the spell will of course also be affected by increased elemental or cold damage.

Comment: thank you very much, good explanation. Can you please elaborate on "It will also be affected by AoE or Bow modifiers since it has that in the main skill gem description (the latter because you are using a bow). The cold portion of the spell will of course also be affected by increased elemental or cold damage."

Comment: @RustamIssabekov I added some additional information. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Caustic Arrow has two separate damage calculations, one for the projectile and one for the area degen. Added cold damage only applies to hits, it doesn't apply to the degen so it's not modified by area damage when using Caustic Arrow. 
Additionally the cold damage is not affected by "increased physical damage with bows" modifiers because it's not physical. There's no such thing "increased damage with bows" modifiers. (The degen is also not affected by those modifiers).

Comment: Also worth linking to the wiki because CA has so many exceptions. https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Caustic_Arrow

Comment: Just to be pedantic, there are in fact two nodes with "Increased damage with bows".  "Aspect of the eagle" and "Bow damage and attack speed", the two nodes just to the right of the upper right node in the screenshot linked.

Answer (score 3):

You have 71% increased Projectile Damage from your skill tree.  Caustic Arrow is an attack skill that fires projectiles, so the added cold damage would also be modified by that 71%.

> Min Damage: 6 * (1 + .71) = 10.26
>
> Max Damage: 9 * (1 + .71) = 15.39

You can also see this in your main physical damage from the bow.